# .NET Compact Fw 3.5: Where is the numeric updown control?

Tags: .net, compact-framework

According to the MSDN the [NumericUpDown class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) is supported by the compact framework. The problem is that I can't find it on the toolbox. Is it possible to add this control to the form in the designer, if yes, how?

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in a Windows Form or Windows Form UserControl, this should be a control listed in the toolbox.

Make sure you're not in a WPF window first.  If that's not the case, you can right click on the toolbox background, and choose "Reset Toolbox".  This should add the NumericUpDown class to the toolbox.  It may be listed in "All Controls" and not in the "Common" controls.

Answer (score 0):

It is there, in the toolbox.  But you might have to look under "All Device Control"

The class in in System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown